# How do you complete a CompletableFuture when another set of CompletableFutures is complete?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I have a completable future (future1) which create 10 completable futures (futureN). Is there a way to set future1 as complete only when all futureN are completed?

Comment: Any code to go along with this question? Not sure what you mean by "completed"

Comment: If `future1` submits the other futures, why don't you just call the blocking operation [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--), which will block `future1` until the other futures can return a result (complete)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CompletableFuture` is not something that *acts* so I'm unsure what you mean by

> which create 10 completable futures

I'm assuming you mean you submitted a task with `runAsync` or `submitAsync`. My example won't, but the behavior is the same if you do.

Create your root [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Then run some code asynchronously that creates your futures (through an `Executor`, [`runAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-), inside a new `Thread`, or inline with `CompletableFuture` return values). Collect the 10 `CompletableFuture` objects and use [`CompletableFuture#allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to get a `CompletableFuture` that will complete when they are all complete (exceptionally or otherwise). You can then add a continuation to it with [`thenRun`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenRun-java.lang.Runnable-) to complete your root future.

For example

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> root = new CompletableFuture<>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("first");
        CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("second");

        System.out.println("running");
        CompletableFuture.allOf(cf1, cf2).thenRun(() -> root.complete("some value"));
    });

    // once the internal 10 have completed (successfully)
    root.thenAccept(r -> {
        System.out.println(r); // "some value"
    });

    Thread.sleep(100);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean by "future creates other futures" but if you have many futures and you want to do something when they are completed you can do it this way:
`CompletableFuture.allOf(future2, future3, ..., futureN).thenRun(() -> future1.complete(value));`